# Can't upload aspx to site assets

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I just created a new site on SharePoint online. I'm trying to upload a file called `index.aspx` into site assets but I keep getting

> `index.aspx`  Sorry, your files couldn't be uploaded. The upload might be too large or the server might be experiencing high network traffic.

I've enabled publishing features just in case but that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to upload a file, you can try through the UI or SharePoint designer. Try them. Most often then not, this is a intermittent issue with o365, just give it some time and try again. The issue would most likely be solved by then.

A workaround is to just create `index.aspx` and copy all the content of your file to it.

Comment: I ended up create a new site collection and that fixed the issue completely. I was initially using the default collection o365 came with